# How can I merge data from two different raters for the same dataset?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroimaging

We're analyzing patient MRI sections of the brain for tumour volume. We do this manually, frame by frame, drawing the borders of the tumour. To ensure more accurate results, we have used two different raters with similar experience. There are differences in two raters' results for different patients. What would be the best method to merge these two data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Rather than merging the data, if you have two measurements of each patient, consider modeling the dependency in the data directly (e.g., with a mixed model). Less efficient but also valid would be to take the average volume of both raters. This also reduces measurement error.